# Does SCons ParseFlags() work with MSVC?

Tags: scons

SCons has a `ParseFlags()` function to turn a compiler command line into build variables. Does this work for MSVC, or does that even make sense?

Comment: What does the SCons documentation say about this?

Comment: Thanks. I was probably looking at outdated documentation that was less specific (but higher up in Google, meh), or just didn't see that sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page does say "Parses one or more strings containing typical command-line flags for GCC tool chains", while the user manual says "Historically, it was created to support the ParseConfig method, so it focuses on options used by the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) for the C and C++ toolchains." It is for GCC.